# function required to split an array within a dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need some help writing a code in R to mutate a dataframe. Below you will find what my dataframe looks like. The last column which is 'genres' contains an array and needs to be split into multiple columns within the dataframe.

```
     id value                            name movies_95_04 main_genre
1     0     8                  Tordy, G\xe9za           10     Comedy
2     1    40              Reviczky, G\xe1bor           17     Comedy
3    10    42                   Cserna, Antal           19      Drama
4   100   229                  Marcella, Jade          178      Adult
5  1000     9               Delarive, Mathieu           13      Drama
6 10000    12 De Grandpr\xe9, Fr\xe9d\xe9rick           11      Drama
                                                                          genres
1               Adventure:1,Animation:1,Comedy:2,Family:1,NULL:3,Romance:1,War:1
2            Comedy:7,Crime:2,Fantasy:1,Musical:1,NULL:2,Romance:2,Short:1,War:1
3 Adventure:1,Animation:1,Comedy:2,Drama:5,Fantasy:1,NULL:5,Romance:3,Thriller:1
4                                              Adult:135,Crime:1,NULL:41,Short:1
5                                       Comedy:1,Drama:2,Horror:1,NULL:7,Short:2
6                                   Comedy:1,Drama:5,NULL:3,Romance:1,Thriller:1
```

This is what I've done so far but instead its giving me a new dataframe which contains empty cells in it.

```
Merged_actors2_ <- str_split_fixed(Merged_actors$genres, ",", 19)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example using `dput()` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Split the data on comma (`,`) into separate rows, separate them into two columns splitting on colon (`:`) and get the data in wide format.

```
library(tidyr)

Merged_actors %>%
  separate_rows(genres, sep = ',') %>%
  separate(genres, c('category', 'value'), sep = ':', convert = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = value, values_fill = 0)

#     id name  movies_95_04 main_genre Adventure Animation Comedy Family
#  <int> <chr>        <int> <chr>          <int>     <int>  <int>  <int>
#1     0 Tord…           10 Comedy             1         1      2      1
#2     1 Revi…           17 Comedy             0         0      7      0
#3    10 Cser…           19 Drama              1         1      2      0
#4   100 Marc…          178 Adult              0         0      0      0
#5  1000 Dela…           13 Drama              0         0      1      0
#6 10000 DeGr…           11 Drama              0         0      1      0
# … with 11 more variables: `NULL` <int>, Romance <int>, War <int>,
#   Crime <int>, Fantasy <int>, Musical <int>, Short <int>, Drama <int>,
#   Thriller <int>, Adult <int>, Horror <int>
```

**data**

```
Merged_actors <- structure(list(id = c(0L, 1L, 10L, 100L, 1000L, 10000L), value = c(8L, 
40L, 42L, 229L, 9L, 12L), name = c("Tordy,G<e9>za", "Reviczky,G<e1>bor", 
"Cserna,Antal", "Marcella,Jade", "Delarive,Mathieu", "DeGrandpr<e9>,Fr<e9>d<e9>rick"
), movies_95_04 = c(10L, 17L, 19L, 178L, 13L, 11L), main_genre = c("Comedy", 
"Comedy", "Drama", "Adult", "Drama", "Drama"), genres = c("Adventure:1,Animation:1,Comedy:2,Family:1,NULL:3,Romance:1,War:1", 
"Comedy:7,Crime:2,Fantasy:1,Musical:1,NULL:2,Romance:2,Short:1,War:1", 
"Adventure:1,Animation:1,Comedy:2,Drama:5,Fantasy:1,NULL:5,Romance:3,Thriller:1", 
"Adult:135,Crime:1,NULL:41,Short:1", "Comedy:1,Drama:2,Horror:1,NULL:7,Short:2", 
"Comedy:1,Drama:5,NULL:3,Romance:1,Thriller:1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```